# How to design my messaging application to be compliant with Spring Integration Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

[image]

I have the messaging application that is working but it is not designed in an elegant way (please, see the image).  My manager is a fan of Spring Integration, so he suggests me to change this application according to the Spring Integration Pattern (version 3).    For sending I use  the LedgerMessage that is serialized by Spring SimpleMessageConverter and is sent in the client by the Spring Amqp Template.

As one can see in the diagram sending the LedgerMessage is originated in the several places,  and the content of the message is different.  Once the message is received by the sender I have several options to process  the message based on the value of Long orderId.  Choosing  a processing method based on ordereId is not really elegant way, because if orderId is positive it is used for further processing.

In case of errors I use log4j to simply log the error.  Theoretically we can send an email informing about the error. Also, we can send an email informing about the end of batch operations taking a long time.
So, any suggestion, especially with graphical presentation is appreciated.

Comment: I would love to help you, but I cannot fully understand the question (I work on ledger systems which heavily use messaging :). If you want to simplify how the message is processed you can request the clients to add a header with the type of ledger, then in Spring Integration you can route messages based on the header into a specific class that deals with that ledger type. A word of warning: SI is quite good, but only use it at the edge of your application, never in the core of it (regardless of what the SI team suggests)